# Setting a field on an object that is a property in a class using reflection in .NET

Tags: .net, reflection

I have the following class structure (pseudocode):

```
Class A
{
  Property string Who;
  Property string Where;
}

Class B
{
  Property A Information;
}

Class C
{
   Property String Who;
}
```

I am trying to find out how to set set `B.A.Who = C.Who` using reflection in .NET 4.0.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this isn't all that difficult to do *sort of* correctly, but it would get really messy if you wanted argument-validation, graceful error-handling etc. Here's an example that should highlight the technique (no checks):

```
static void SetBsAsWhoToCsWho(object b, object c)
{
    // csWho = c.Who
    object csWho = c.GetType().GetProperty("Who").GetValue(c, null);

    // a = b.Information
    object a = b.GetType().GetProperty("Information").GetValue(b, null);

    // a.Who = csWho
    a.GetType().GetProperty("Who").SetValue(a, csWho, null);
}
```

You need all sorts of checks in the above code to make it robust. It would really help if you could tell us *why* you want to use reflection to accomplish this task. Depending on the scenario, there may be solutions that are more appropriate, such as:

1. The obvious type-safe code.
2. Casting as necessary, followed by type-safe code.
3. Generating a delegate by constructing and compiling an expression-tree.
4. The use of `dynamic`.
5. AutoMapper and other libraries.